# An error occurred evaluating root project .Could not create plugin of type 'AppPlugin'

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, android-gradle-plugin

**I have 18 applications which I am trying to execute using Gradle.
I have tried Gradle(1.6,1.8.1.9,1.10)
While executing I am getting this error :**

```
BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.817 secs

D:\ABC\DEF>gradle build

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\ABC\DEF\build.gradle' line: 10

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'ABC'.
> Could not create plugin of type 'AppPlugin'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 6.536 secs
```

**My build.gradle file is :**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.3'
        classpath 'de.felixschulze.gradle:gradle-app-plugin:1.1+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'App'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':libraries:NavigationDrawer')
    compile project(':libraries:google-play-services_lib')

    compile files('libs/android-rome-feed-reader-1.0.0-r2.jar')
    compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.2.jar')
    debugCompile files('libs/SDK-3.0.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/jdom-1.1.1-android-fork.jar')
    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar')  
}
/*
 * upload to vette2 server
*/

task uploadToVette2(type: Exec) {
    commandLine './scripts/uploadToVette2.sh'
}
/*
 * upload to app server
 * will pass a paramter named:note
 * we can call it like this: gradle uploadToApp -Pnote="some note here"
*/
task uploadToApp(type: Exec) {
    commandLine './scripts/uploadToApp.sh'
    if (project.hasProperty("note")){
        args note
    }

}

app {
    apiToken = "19b1ba1d36ab4299a09a302f34169fe1"
    releaseType = 2 // alpha
    notify = 0
    status = 2
    notesType = 1
    notes = "Some notes."
    symbolsDirectory = file("build/symbols/")
    mappingFileNameRegex = "R.txt"
}

android {

    defaultConfig { 
       minSdkVersion 9
       targetSdkVersion 9
    }
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    productFlavors {
        tigers {
            packageName "com.xx.aa"
        }

        bb {
            packageName "com.xx.bb"
        }
        cc {
            packageName "com.xx.cc"
        }
```

and so on.

Thanks for your replies

Comment: Have you tried to use a newer build plugin (ex: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.2'` should work with gradle 1.10/1.11)?

Comment: We tried with gradle 1.10 & 1.11 but we are getting this error : "A problem occurred evaluating root project 'LSMobileAppBranch'.
> The SDK directory 'D:\AA\BB\adt-bundle-windows-x86-201309
17sdk' does not exist."

Comment: Do you have the correct build tools installed? ("17.0.0")

Comment: Yes i have it correctly installed

Comment: It's failing somewhere trying to use the `App` plugin you have configured. Follow its advice in the error message and build from the command line with the --stacktrace option. That should give you more output to work with.

Comment: I was able to resolve the above issue but now am getting error as "Project with path ':libraries:google-play-services_lib' could not be found in
project".   My Google Play services are at proper path.